# Setting up mysqlclient for python3 on ubuntu mate

Tags: mysql, python3, django

I am having getting the following error when setting up mysql:

```
Setting up python-mysqldb (1.3.4-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-mysqldb.postinst: 6:
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-mysqldb.postinst: pycompile: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing package python-mysqldb (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing: python-mysqldb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Much of what I try ends up with that error message. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

May I be the first to say Welcome to AskUbuntu! As many users look at this, this is a very simple problem, and someday you will look back on this later in your Ubuntu adventure, and chuckle too.

The problem is you are not running the command with `sudo`. This command will run anything you type as *root*, or as the most powerful user on your system. If you do not have access to the root password (which is the same as your first installed user on your pc), you will not be able to run `sudo` successfully.

I do not know the command you used, but if it was:

```
apt-get install mysql
```

It would then be:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql
```

Terminal will then ask you for your password. Enter it, and hit <kbd>Return</kbd>, then mysqyl will install.

Comment: Hi there. I actually was using sudo apt-get install. However, i tried typing in that exact command but it just said " to locate mysql".

Comment: *unable to locate

Comment: Like I said, I don't know if that was the command, and I don't know the command, that was just an example of how to use `sudo` @M.dike